# After changing text in a cell, it fails to evaluate last step of a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I'm facing a really odd and annoying issue with formulas that I'm not succeeding in fix it.

It happens the following: I received an Excel .xlsx via Outlook (but I also tried using USB).

When I open it for the first time, in a cell (BB9) there is a Text formatted cell showing November-2019.

In the first column the formula

```
=IF( ISERROR(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(G14,"-",$BB$9)),2)), 0, WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(G14,"-",$BB$9)),2))
```

It returns a number that is used as a reference in a table to return a General formatted cell that show the two initial characters of the day of the week.

This is the referenced table:

```
Days    Week    
Giorni  Settimana   
1       lu (Monday)
2       ma (Tuesday and so on) theoretically correct value
3       me
4       gi
5       ve
6       sa
7       do
0       -- (actually failing value)
```

As it is 1-November-2019 the cell contains "ve" (It stands for Friday as I'm from Italy).

Here the problem arise: if I change BB9 in May-2019 the formula evaluation fails at the last step (returning 0 and referencing the table that in turns return a
-- string.

I debugged the formula evaluation and everything is equal except for the last evaluation. In the November scenario formula returns 5 (correct), in the May scenario formula returns 0 (the correct value is 2) and I don't understand the reason.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I cut & paste unformatted. Here's the right version.

Comment: Let's see if I successfully format. Hi to everyone, I'm facing a really odd and annoying  
issue with formulas that I'm not succeeding in fix it.  
It happens the following: I received an Excel .xlsx  
via Outlook (but I also tried using USB).  
When I open it for the first time, in a cell (BB9)
there is a Text formatted cell showing November-2019.  
In the first column the formula  
=IF( ISERROR(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE  
(G14,"-",$BB$9)),2)), 0, WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE  
(CONCATENATE(G14,"-",$BB$9)),2)) returns a number  
that is used as a reference in a table.

Comment: It returns a General formatted cell that show the two initial  
characters of the day of the week.  
This is the referenced table:  
Days    Week   
Giorni Settimana   
1 lu (Monday)  
**2 ma (Tuesday and so on)** theoretically correct value  
3 me  
4 gi  
5 ve  
6 sa  
7 do  
**0 --** actually failing value

Comment: As it is 1-November-2019 the cell contains "ve"  
(It stands for Friday as I'm from Italy).  
Here the problem arise: if I change BB9 in May-2019  
the formula evaluation fails at the last step  
returning 0 and referencing the table that in turns  
return a -- string in G column.
I debugged the formula evaluation and everything is equal  
except for the last evaluation. In the November scenario  
formula returns 5 (correct), in the May scenario formula  
returns 0 (the correct value is 2) and I don't understand  
the reason. Can someone help me ?  
Kind regards, Andrea Ceschia

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not yet able to format. My apologies if it confusing

Comment: Please **edit** (see the "edit" button below the tags) your question. Comments are not intended for additional info related to your question. Comments can also not be formatted as the question. After editing your question, please delete superfluous comments.

Comment: What is in `G14`?

Comment: @AndreaCeschia i edited your question to address formatting so you should delete these comments. If you don't understand how formatting work, it's based on Markdown and there is a [help section](https://superuser.com/editing-help) just for that.

Comment: Hi Tom and CaldeiraG, I appreciate your suggestions. It was my first approach to this platform then I was I little bit in difficult. Kind regards, Andrea

Answer (score 1):

I solved with an hint coming from a colleague: it was a language related issue.
File > Options > Language > italian Keyboard Layout and Proofing weren't installed.
I installed them and now everything works fine.
Kind regards,
Andrea Ceschia